# sharing GCP image using api

Tags: api, curl, google-cloud-platform, python-requests, postman

I have been trying to share my GCP image with other accounts using API... on the UI I can do it in permissions and by adding members...

I used the following URL with the post request:

`POST https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/PROJECT_ID/global/images/IMAGE_NAME:getIamPolicy`

with headers `'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'`

and with data:

```
                            {"version": "0",
                             "bindings":
                                 [
                                        {
                                            "members": ["user:mymailid@gmail.com"],
                                            "role":"roles/compute.imageUser"
                                        }
                                 ]
                             }
                        }
```

bypassing the authorization bearer key,

after hitting it in postman or with curl or in python request, getting a response: `404 Not Found`

I also enabled the API permissions using CLI using `gcloud services enable pubsub.googleapis.com`

what do I need to pass extra to make this work?
hoping I will get help from someone ... Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

@Ganesh

To set IAM Policy, you need to use different url.

```
POST https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/PROJECT_ID/global/images/IMAGE_NAME/setIamPolicy

json({
  "version": "0",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "members": ["user:mymailid@gmail.com"],
      "role": "roles/compute.imageUser"
    }
  ]
})
```

Note:

- replace projectId
- replace imagename

reference:
[google-docs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/beta/images/setIamPolicy), [collection](https://github.com/cedric05/the-api-evanglist/blob/a5ac568ecebab413c7156fe2a6614b1aaeb9fc7d/collections/Cloud_User_Accounts/project/global/groups/resource/imported_from_collection.http#L14), [Dothttp](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ShivaPrasanth.dothttp-code)

Comment: yes, it is working fine, thanks @prasanth but, while adding a new user, the old one is vanishing and updating with only a new one... is it by default, or does something need to change? manually, it can be adding and works with multiple users

Comment: and as per the documentation, you provided: ``` setIamPolicy: Sets the access control policy on the specified resource. Replaces any existing policy.``` what we can do to not to effect the existing policy

Comment: I have seen seOrgPolicy can append on the existing policy... I am not sure but tried, giving 404 error,  what should I do to make it work?or with any other alternative...